# Creating custom gridView item, using xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-gridview

I'm using the following `RelativeLayout` for creating an item in `GridView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_service"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="268dp"        
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:text="My text"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_service"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:ellipsize="marquee">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

which gives me this:

[image]

Instead, what I want is this:

[image]

Comment: [check this url](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/staggeredgridview-by-maurycy-wojtowicz/) and customize it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Image view is at right position,
Below, instead of putting textview directly..
put a linearlayout their with orientation horizontal,
and make two childs of this LinearLayout, TextView and ImageView...
thats it..

Answer (score 1):

You are providing only one ImageView and expecting for two imageviews see your code..for achiving your desired result take one linear layout ,give it wightsum = 10 and orientation vertical and take one Image and another linerlayout inside this.give weight for imageview 7 and linearlayout 3..then the set the second one linearlayout weightsum equal to 6 and take one textview and one imageview inside the second layout and set textview weight equal to 4 and and imageview equal to 2..see the result if not equal to your expecting...customize the weightsums...like

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```